# apache redirect http to https for some page

Tags: apache, redirect

I used this code but error appear

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user/login
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

thanks

[website](http://www.apk.co.ir)

Answer (score 1):

"Using mod_rewrite to do this isn't the recommended behavior. [See RedirectSSL](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL)"

Should to use Virtual Host instead... you can try this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://secure.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName secure.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   SSLEngine On
# etc...
</VirtualHost>
```

With mod_rewrite will should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
```